# What is the "right" way to add a file to a panel in KDE

Tags: kde, kde-4, kde-plasma-workspace

Adding a widget or program to a panel in KDE is easy: apps can be added from kickstart, and widgets via the normal panel settings.

But if I have a file, such as a libreoffice document, the process I use is convoluted:

1. I drag the document to the desktop to create a shortcut
2. Drag from the desktop to a panel to get it into the panel
3. Delete the desktop shortcut
4. Inevitably have to modify the icon in the panel from the generic one to one that matches the document

I am thinking there is a better way to do this, I just don't see it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 with KDE 4.10.
I can add files to the panel just by dragging them onto it. For me it works by dragging both from Dolphin and Plasma (i.e. Kickstart or Folder View plasmoid).

Of course you have to make sure to have unlocked desktop Plasma Items, or the panel will be locked too.

Please note that you need a little precision work to catch the right spots where the launchers could be put, you have to aim for a blank spot between a toolbar item and another (i.e. the space between the Task Manager and the Kickoff button); when you are over a legitimate spot, you will see a greyed square, then you can release here the file and the link will be properly created.